# Why remote command center not show in simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, simulator, mpremotecommandcenter

I wanna show command center in lock screen but it work on real device and not working on simulator.

Comment: thank you  @WaynePhipps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple remove `RemoteCommandCenter` simulation since iOS 11,

so i suggest you to use iOS 10.x simulator to debug `RemoteCommandCenter`.